# MySQL where IN from joined table

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

```
i have 2 tables (example):

product:

|  id | name                |
|  1  | product1            |
|  2  | product2            |
|  3  | product3            |

product_categories:

|  product_id | category_id |
|      1      |      5      |
|      1      |      3      |
|      2      |      5      |
|      3      |      17     |
|      3      |      5      |
```

and i want to select those products which category id is 5 and 3.

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM products p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN product_categories pc 
    ON pc.product_id = p.id
 WHERE ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point to use `LEFT JOIN` since you do not want unmatched rows.
Group by product and set the condition for the product to have both categories in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM products p INNER JOIN product_categories pc 
ON pc.product_id = p.id
WHERE pc.category_id IN (3, 5)
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.category_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON (pc.product_id = p.id) 
WHERE category_id IN (5,3)
```

Comment: This is also an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON (pc.product_id = p.id) AND pc.category_id in (3,5);

(in case you do want unmatched rows)
```

Or

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p INNER JOIN product_categories pc ON (pc.product_id = p.id) WHERE pc.category_id in (3,5)

(if you're sure that you don't)
```

Comment: Note that this is an INNER JOIN

Comment: Edited for clarity